# How to say copycat?

Tags: word-requests

I posted a status on Facebook and 20 minutes later someone else posted the exact same one. Google translate spits out 复印机 for *copycat* which looks pretty weird to me (the 机 at the end). Nciku gave me 模仿者 which looks better (the 者 at the end). How can I say something akin to 'copycat' in Mandarin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`模仿者` means `imitator`, which isn't necessarily negative, and is used more for behavior imitation instead of content crib, but I think it is fine to use for your case.

For intellectual property plagiarism, the common words are `抄袭` (lit. copy and assault) and `剽窃` (lit. rob and steal). Both words are formal and strong but the latter one is even stronger. You can say someone is a `抄袭者` if he cribbed your exam answer, or `剽窃者` if he plagiarized your work.

Note in Chinese, `xx者` usually indicates a behavior pattern or long-term state, while in English `-er` form is merely a language tool to convert a verb into a noun and is commonly used for one-time actions. So if you call someone `模仿者` it usually means this person always imitates somebody. If it's just this one time, I'd prefer to say '他抄(袭)了我的状态更新' instead of '他是个抄袭者'.

BTW if that person is not a human account, like a robot who cribs status updates and wall posts to look credible, we call them `僵尸(账)号` (lit. zombie account), `机器人` (lit. robot) or `僵尸粉` (lit. zombie follower).

Answer (score 2):

In this context, I would use:

> 跟屁虫 [gēn pì chóng]

Similar to the English word "copycat", it is an *informal* noun used to describe a person who imitates, tags along or copies the idea or behaviour of another person.

Answer (score 1):

山寨。

> China is home to copycatters. 中国是山寨之乡。
>
> Every innovation gets copycatted by China. 每个创新都被中国山寨。

In your example however, `抄袭` and `剽窃` are the most accurate.

Answer (score 0):

复读机

[维基百科页面](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%8D%E8%AF%BB%E6%9C%BA)

“你复读机啊你？”

Stupid character counter bah